# React - Quiero pintar todos los elementos de mi arreglo de objetos en una <ol/>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Soy novato en React y estoy tratando de pintar en una  todos los elementos de mi arreglo de objetos, el cual obtengo de un endpoint. En la imagen sólo se muestra un objeto como ejemplo.

```
export const PublicationList = () => {

const [publications, setPublications] = useState([{
  id: "",
  title: "",
  body: ""
}])

useEffect(() => {
  fetchPublications()
  return () => {
  }
}, []);

const fetchPublications = async () => {

  let respuestas = await obtenerPublicacion();

  setPublications([{
    id: respuestas[0].id,
    title: respuestas[0].title,
    body: respuestas[0].body
}]);
}

}
```

[image: Código y vista del arreglo de objetos en consola]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque estás asignando solo el primer elemento en

```
  setPublications([{
    id: respuestas[0].id,
    title: respuestas[0].title,
    body: respuestas[0].body
}]);
```

Sin saber lo que efectivamente viene desde `obtenerPublicacion()` creo que debería ser:

```
  setPublications(respuestas);
```

Comment: Exacto, sólo agregué el primer elemento como ejemplo de lo que queria hacer, pero tu respuesta me solucionó el problema, gracias!